# What is the ideal way to label version histories in TFS?

Tags: tfs

In the development of our software we create releases that are specific to currently existing customers.  there are many similarities between our releases but ultimately they must be considered separate versions of the software.  Because all releases are built upon the same code with only slight differences, in what manner should labeling and version be performed?

Comment: That's a very, very broad question that doesn't have a single, correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first apply a good branching strategy. You could create one branch for each customer and let the common code base live in the main branch. As for versioning you should consider using one version number for the common code base and a separate version number series for each customer specific branch.